# Quiz Applications

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I started a simple quiz application as below it consists of `TextView` to show the questions and a `RadioGroup` consisting of 3 `RadioButtons` for 3 options. When you finish the quiz it shows number of correct answers and number of wrong answers and your degree. But I have some problems as below Please help me to solve it.

the problems:

1. When i click on next question its transfer me to result activity not to next questions.
2. The Result activity page did not show the total result correctly

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView tv;
Button btnNext;
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3;

String questions[]={"qqqqq","dddddd"};
String ans[]={"",""};
String opt[]={"","","","","",""};

int flag=0;
public static int marks,correct,wrong;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvque);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);

        tv.setText(questions[flag]);
        rb1.setText(opt[0]);
        rb2.setText(opt[1]);
        rb3.setText(opt[2]);

        Toast.makeText(this,"Nigative mark", 1000).show();

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                RadioButton uans=(RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                String ansText=uans.getText().toString();

                if(ansText.equalsIgnoreCase(ans[flag]))
                {

                    correct++;  
                }
                else
                {
                    wrong++;
                }
                flag++;
                if(flag<questions.length)
                {
                    tv.setText(questions[flag]);
                    rb1.setText(opt[flag*3]);
                    rb2.setText(opt[(flag*3)+1]);
                    rb3.setText(opt[(flag*3)+2]);

                }
                else
                {
                    marks=correct;

                }

                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**ResultActivity**

```
public class ResultActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView tv;
    Button btRestart;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        btRestart=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("Correct ANS:"+MainActivity.correct);
        sb.append("Wrong ANS:"+MainActivity.wrong);
        sb.append("Final Score:"+MainActivity.marks);
        tv.setText(sb);

        MainActivity.correct=0;
        MainActivity.wrong=0;

        btRestart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);


            }
        });         
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. How about judiciously editing it to show the [shortest, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem at hand?

Comment: I have edited this time. Please see [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26367791/revisions) to have a better idea of how to format posts and to only post **most relevant ** code. Also, code snippets are for runnable code. Use code blocks instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. When i click on next question its transfer me to result activity not to next questions.

   You are telling it to go to the `ResultsActivity` in your `Intent`

```
// 2nd param is the target Activity
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);  
startActivity(i);
```

To fix that, you would need to use the name of the `Activity` where your next question is to replace `ResultActivity`. Unless you store them in an `Array` or other type of list then you could just replace the question `TextView` text with the next question.

2. The Result activity page did not show the total result correctly

   This is nearly impossible to answer without knowing your expected and actual results.

Comment: how can i fix the first issue (next question)

Comment: See my edit. You need to decide where you store the questions and how you want to present them. You may want to look through some examples of posts people have asked here or look up tutorials on The Google.